# Dúvida para fazer integração entre sistemas web, utilizando HttpWebRequest- Linguagem c#

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, integração

Estou construindo uma aplicação web em C# usando o VS 2010.

Nesta aplicação preciso trocar informações entre o site da empresa e um site externo.

Só que este site não tem nenhum componente para troca de informação, somente é possível enviar informação acessando o site através de credencial e navegando entre os menus e informando os dados manualmente.

O desafio é criar uma automação/integração para isso. Consultando na internet, estou vendo muitas coisas em especial sobre HttpWebRequest que seria o caminho.
Alguém já viu ou fez algo parecido, onde tenha que selecionar um item de menu, preencher os itens da página selecionada mandar processar e pegar resultados?

Answer (score 0):

O que você está tentando fazer é um [Web Crawler](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastreador_web). A ideia é basicamente ir fazendo requisições HTTP para a aplicação em questão, executar um *parse* das páginas HTML retornadas e, a partir do conteúdo obtido delas, fazer mais requisições.

Para ter uma base inicial, você pode tentar utilizar esse artigo [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1087859/web-crawling-with-csharp).

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, vou dar uma olhada na indicação. Estou testando o selenium está atendendo, mas o problema é que abre o browser e toda navegação é visualizada, não seria necessário o usuário ficar vendo o processo...